# Oracle: извлечь из строки слово с определенным префиксом:

Tags: строки, oracle

Добрый день.

Как в Oracle извлечь из строки слово или слова с определенным префиксом. 
Допустим имеется строка "element 1, element 2, element 1 - acc.block, element 2 - acc.batch" - из этой строки нужны все слова с префиксом "acc."

на входе: "element 1, element 2, element 1 - acc.block, element 2 - acc.batch", 
на выходе: "acc.block", "acc.batch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with Q as(
 select 'element 1, element 2, element 1 - acc.block, element 2 - acc.batch'
        as str from DUAL
)

select regexp_substr(str, 'acc\.\w+', 1, level) from Q
 connect by regexp_substr(str, 'acc\.\w+', 1, level) is not null;
```